# using big bang to grow image

Tags: scheme, racket

Trying to use big-bang to make a program that grows the image/text “How Are You”.  I want to make the text size start at 1 and stop growing until it reaches size 80.

This is what I have so far:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
  (require 2htdp/universe)




    (define word "How Are You" )

    (define (draw-world world)
      (place-image (text world 1 "olive")
                   100 100
                   (empty-scene 200 200)))

    (big-bang word

         (on-draw draw-world))
```

I have the text, but it wont grow until it reaches text size 80. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

World programs need to subscribe to what stimuli they'll be watching.  Your program does not at all register with any stimuli, so there's no change in the world.

Look at [on-tick](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html#%28form._%28%28lib._2htdp/universe..rkt%29._on-tick%29%29).  For examples, please look at [Picturing Programs](http://picturingprograms.com), [Chapter 6](http://picturingprograms.com/download/chap06.pdf).  It talks about how to do animations.  Search for the use of `on-tick` there, and you should see it.